# applescript click missing value

Tags: applescript

```
tell application "Google Chrome" to activate
delay 0.5
tell application "System Events"
    tell process "Google Chrome"
        click at {1067, 79}
        click at {1026, 220}
    end tell
end tell
```

here is my applescript, I tried to open and extension by first click in chrome and then second click to download the video inside of the extension, however, only the first command was executed and the second return "missing value". I don't know why. I've also tried add a delay between the two command, it still doesn't work. Any one can help?

Answer (score 0):

```
tell application "Google Chrome" to activate
delay 0.5
tell application "System Events"
    tell process "Google Chrome"
        click at {1067, 79}
delay 1
        click at {1026, 220}
    end tell
end tell
```

if this is what you mean^ then try this:

```
tell application "Google Chrome" to activate
delay 0.5
tell application "System Events"
    tell process "Google Chrome"
        click at {1067, 79}
    end tell
end tell
delay 0.5
tell application "Google Chrome" to activate
tell application "System Events"
    tell process "Google Chrome"
        click at {1026, 220}
    end tell
end tell
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that if it "can't click" it will return "missing value" for a given coordinates.

This seems to happen for instance when I click into a chrome browser.  If I click into Safari, it works great.  If I click into a firefox, it returns and says it clicked, but doesn't actually do anything in the browser.  Weird.

Workaround: Use 3rd party app MouseTools to click instead.  Refs:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/12887429/32453

https://stackoverflow.com/a/22595044/32453

Though I suppose you could write your own obj-c code to do it as well, etc.